# Django QuerySet slicing returning unexpected results

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm dynamically writing a Django query and am receiving unexpected results based on the slice parameters.  For example, if I request **queryset[0:10]** and **querset[10:20]** I receive some of the same item's in query2 that I found in query1.

Searching around, the issue I'm facing appears similar to:

[Simple Djanqo Query generating confusing Queryset results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843687/simple-djanqo-query-generating-confusing-queryset-results)

except I am defining a order_by for my query so it doesn't appear to be an exact match.

Viewing the querset.query for my two queries....

queryset[0:10] generates:

```
SELECT "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."id",
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."part", 
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."site", 
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."location",
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."hadTransactionsDuring"
FROM   "intercache_localinventorycountsummary" 
ORDER BY "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."hadTransactionsDuring" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

queryset[10:20] generates:

```
SELECT "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."id",
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."part", 
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."site", 
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."location",
       "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."hadTransactionsDuring"
FROM   "intercache_localinventorycountsummary" 
ORDER BY "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."hadTransactionsDuring" DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Per request, I've listed the literal SQL generated by Django, and ran it manually against the DB.

Results for Query1:

```
  id  |  part   | site | location | hadTransactionsDuring
------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------
 2787 | 2217-1  | 01   | Bluebird | t
 2839 | 2215    | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2558 | R4367   | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 2637 | 4453    | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2810 | 1000    | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2531 | 3475    | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2526 | 4596Z   | 01   | 2550 FG  | t
 2590 | 3237-12 | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 3077 | 4841Y   | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2919 | 3407    | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
```

Results for Query2:

```
  id  |     part     | site | location | hadTransactionsDuring
------+--------------+------+----------+-----------------------
 2598 | 2217-2       | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 2578 | 2216-5       | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 2531 | 3475         | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 3010 | 3919         | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2558 | R4367        | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 2637 | 4453         | 01   | 2600 FG  | t
 2526 | 4596Z        | 01   | 2550 FG  | t
 2590 | 3237-12      | 01   | 2600 Raw | t
 2570 | R3760-BRN-GS | 01   | 2600 Raw | f
 2569 | 4098         | 01   | 2600 FG  | f
```

(You can see id's 2558, 2637, 2526, 2590 are returned for both queries)

Any guesses what I'm doing wrong here?  It seem I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something about how QuerySet slicing works.

## Update:

**The DB schema is as follows... are result orderings non-reliable when ordering by non-indexed fields perhaps?**

```
\d intercache_localinventorycountsummary
                                         Table "public.intercache_localinventorycountsummary"
        Column         |           Type           |                                     Modifiers
-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                  | not null default nextval('intercache_localinventorycountsummary_id_seq'::regclass)
 _domain_id            | integer                  |
 _created              | timestamp with time zone | not null
 _synced               | timestamp with time zone |
 _active               | boolean                  | not null default true
 dirty                 | boolean                  | not null default true
 lastRefresh           | timestamp with time zone |
 part                  | character varying(18)    | not null
 site                  | character varying(8)     | not null
 location              | character varying(8)     | not null
 quantity              | numeric(16,9)            |
 startCount            | timestamp with time zone |
 endCount              | timestamp with time zone |
 erpCountQOH           | numeric(16,9)            |
 hadTransactionsDuring | boolean                  | not null default false
 quantityChangeSince   | numeric(16,9)            |
 hadManualDating       | boolean                  | not null
 variance              | numeric(16,9)            |
 unitCost              | numeric(16,9)            |
 countCost             | numeric(16,9)            |
 varianceCost          | numeric(16,9)            |
Indexes:
    "intercache_localinventorycountsummary_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "intercache_localinventorycount__domain_id_5691b6f8cca017dc_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (_domain_id, part, site, location)
    "intercache_localinventorycountsummary__active" btree (_active)
    "intercache_localinventorycountsummary__domain_id" btree (_domain_id)
    "intercache_localinventorycountsummary__synced" btree (_synced)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "_domain_id_refs_id_163d40e6b21ac0f9" FOREIGN KEY (_domain_id) REFERENCES intercache_domain(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the underlying table.

Comment: You'll need to show the underlying table contents. We can't really comment on the output without seeing the input.

Comment: What happens if you run those same queries directly in the db shell?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the command you used to generate the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with this:

```
ORDER BY "intercache_localinventorycountsummary"."hadTransactionsDuring" DESC
```

Apparently you've overridden ordering either explicitly in the query or in model's meta options (vide [Model Meta options: ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)).

If you want to order by `hadTransactionsDuring` but have predictable ordering, you should add second ordering that will resolve cases where first one has same value. For example:

```
queryset.order_by("-hadTransactionsDuring", "id")
```

Keep in mind RDBMSes, be it PostgreSQL or MySQL, *never* guarantee *any order* at all unless explicitly specified with `ORDER BY`. Most queries *usually* return in order of primary key, but that's more like just a happy coincidence, depending on internal implementation of table storage, rather than something you can rely on. In other words you cannot assume that Django queryset is ordered on any field besides the fields you've specified in `order_by`.

Comment: So, my 'update' is correct... results ordering isn't reliable when only sorting by a non-indexed field (hence the need for the id field sort addition)?

Comment: @slumtrimpet: RDBMS *never* guarantee *any order* at all unless explicitly specified with ORDER BY. Most *usually* return in order of primary key, but that's more like just a happy coincidence, rather than something you can rely on.

Comment: @slumtrimpet: also you cannot say that *"result of sorting isn't reliable"*. It's 100% reliable, but *only* on the fields that you've asked results to be sorted on.

Comment: Fair enough... thanks for the reply and clarification.  Makes sense.

Comment: @slumtrimpet: I've added that into the answer itself, should anyone in the future have same doubts.